# ASP.NET app to send an mail with a hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("hkar@gmail.com");

message.Subject = "Subject";
message.Body = "Please login";
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

message.To.Add("karaman@gmail.com");                  
smtp.Send(message);
```

I want to have a hyperlink in the body of sent mail where it says "login". How can I do that?

Comment: If the body is HTML, use the HTML: `<a href="...">login</a>`

Comment: Make sure the body type is html, then just send html.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
message.Body = "Please <a href=\"http://www.example.com/login.aspx\">login</a>";
```

Make sure you highlight when sending that the content is HTML though.

```
message.IsBodyHTML = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the message to `message.IsBodyHTML = true`

```
<a href="http://YourWebsite.Com">Login</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
message.Body = string.Format("Click <a href='{0}'>here</a> to login", loginUrl);
```

Comment: Nice to see an example suitable for a separately generated URL, rather than using a hard coded reference.

Answer (score 0):

Format the message as HTML and make sure to set the IsBodyHtml property on the MailMessage to true:

message.IsBodyHtml = true;

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.Text.StringBuildersb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
 System.Web.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Mail.Web.MailMessage(); 
 mail.To = "recipient@address"; 
 mail.From = "sender"; 
 mail.Subject = "Test"; 
 mail.BodyFormat = System.Web.Mail.MailFormat.Html;
 sb.Append("<html><head><title>Test</title><body>"); //HTML content which you want to send
 mail.Body = sb.ToString();
 System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost"; //Your Smtp Server 
 System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(mail);
```

You just have to set the format of body to html then you can add html element within the bosy of mail message